# Possible to limit list of params when using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React with React-Router in a project and am wondering if it's possible to limit the possibilities for param names, like so:

```
www.mydomain.com/books/:id
```

and allowing 'Catcher in the Rye' and 'To Kill A Mockingbird' to be passed through, like so:

```
www.mydomain.com/books/catcher-in-the-rye
www.mydomain.com/books/to-kill-a-mocking-bird
```

I want to say that only a specific set of books can be used in place of :id (just so someone can't type in www.mydomain.com/books/whatever-they-want and have an empty React component render).

I do currently have a '*' route that catches anything not mentioned, but because params are dynamically generated based on whatever is passed, that won't help in this case.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle this logic in the component. Depending on if this is an already mounted component or not you will need to put the logic in the appropriate function (componentDidMount, componentWillReceiveProps)

```
if(!(this.props.params.id in myAcceptableParameters)){
    redirect to a 404 here
}
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! glad I could help!